# Ensuring uniqueness in generation of entity identifiers within specific constraints

Tags: cryptography, collision-detection

I am a beginner in the field of cryptography, and I have been presented with a challenge that requires the generation of unique identifiers for entities. While UUIDv4, UUIDv7, or ULID were initially considered, the constraints of the task necessitate that the generated value must be equal to or less than 4,738,381,338,321,616,895.

In order to accommodate these constraints, I am considering the adoption of a strategy that is part of the metioned algorithms, specifically, the combination of a timestamp (in milliseconds) with a portion of randomly generated bits. If I were to assign the first 13 characters for the timestamp (up to 4,738,381,338,321), this would leave me with the capacity to generate a random number within the range of 0 to 616,896.

Several questions have arisen as I contemplate this approach:

- What strategies can I employ to ensure uniqueness within these constraints?

  - Initially, the use of a lookup table to verify the originality of each generated number came to mind. Is this the most efficient and effective method available?
- What is the likelihood of generating an identical number between 0 and 616,896 within the same millisecond?
- How do UUIDv4 and ULID ensure collision-free generation of unique identifiers? Is it purely the improbability of generating the same random 128 bits within the same millisecond?

Thank you in advance :)

I've read through the specs of ULID and UUIDv4 to understand more about the algorithms.